# What are some hymns composed by Kotpuli Nayanar?

Tags: shiva, nayanar

What are the songs composed by Kotpuli Nayanar on Lord Siva and in which number he comes out of total 63 Nayanars?

Comment: There is no Nayanar by the name Puli Kundrar. There is Kotpuli Nayanar and Shirappuliyar. Did you mean them?

Comment: Kotpuli nayanar

Comment: If you get please post.